# MapStruct is mapping all boolean values to false

Tags: java, spring-boot, dto, mapstruct

The database has 2 values 1 true and 1 false. When i get response from Postman all values show as false. DB internally stores true as 1 and false as 0. What is causing mapping to be false?

**Company.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
@Size(max = 60)
private String name;

@Size(max = 40)
private String vat;

@Size(max = 12)
private String contact;

private boolean defaultCompany;
```

**CompanyDTO**

```
private Long id;

@NotBlank
@Size(max = 60)
private String name;

@Size(max = 40)
private String vat;

@Size(max = 12)
private String contact;

private boolean defaultCompany;
```

**Mapper**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CompanyMapper
{
    CompanyDTO toCompanyDTO(Company company);
    Company toCompany(CompanyDTO companyDTO);
    List<CompanyDTO> toCompanyDTOS(List<Company> companies);
}
```

**DB Values Snapshot**

[image]

**Postman Snapshot**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything was fine. It was an issue with IntelliJ IDEA not generating the mappings. The issue also mentioned here https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1690.

To resolve the issue remove the `target` directory and rebuild the project now things work perfectly.